# Quantum hadrodynamics

Tags: terminology, definition, hadron-dynamics

What is [quantum hadrodynamics](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=quantum+hadrodynamics)? Can anybody give a proper explanation? 
What are the standard books and sources of information that can be found on the internet for better understanding?

Comment: Not sure the level of seriousness with regards to the last question, but it should be rather obvious that Google is just doing a spelling check (i.e., hydrodynamics is more frequently searched than hadrodynamics).

Comment: oh.. yes. should have considered that. anyway, that is still a legitimate question however childish. a good answer should come up. with the negatives, may be i shud consider deleting the question.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quantum_hadrodynamics vs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_hydrodynamics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hadrons are strongly interacting particles, and at the elementary particle level are studied by [Quantum Chromodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics) within the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model).

Before the standard model became standard, hadrons were studied experimentally and a multitude of  [resonances were found](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2009/listings/contents_listings.html) in meson meson or meson proton interactions. These were studied theoretically using particle exchange models , with Feynman diagrams of one particle exchange , as with [Yukawa couplings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction), or with [vector meson dominance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_meson_dominance) diagarams. These led to a more general [Regge pole exchanges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regge_theory)  ( which is having a come back with string theory, but that is another story).

When the quark model led to the standard model, it became clear that the old phenomenology   was no longer usefull in particle physics. Pion and rho exchanges were superseded by gluon exchanges between elementary particles with hadronic interactions.

In nuclear physics , only the spill over forces from the strong interactions are necessary to describe the behavior of nuclei , and these are well described by the one hadron exchange models as can be seen in the link given in the answer by user74893 . It seems that this branch has been developing in what they call [quantum hadrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_hadrodynamics), in models  used in describing nuclear interactions, though the wikipedia article does not  exist yet.

Comment: Thank you for being direct and straight forward, to the point. Any text book you can mention?

Comment: Sorry, it is not my field. Check in a library the link given by user74893 . It may have references to standard texts there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://journals.aps.org/prc/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevC.52.380

> The effective masses and the screening masses of hadrons at finite temperature and density for the quantum hadrodynamics two (QHD-II) model have been investigated under the one-loop approximation. The nucleon-nucleon interaction through pion, sigma, omega, and rho mesons exchange in hot nuclear matter is given. We have found that the potential well of the nucleon-nucleon interaction becomes shallow as the temperature and/or density increases. At a critical temperature and/or a critical density, the potential well disappears.

It's a genuine field of nuclear physics studies

it's very heavy going but it refers to your word.  If you google hadrons (apologies for this, but do you know what they are?) as well , that might be a help